# How to retrieve CoreData that satisfies a condition swift 2

Tags: swift, core-data, swift2, nsfetchrequest, executefetchrequest

I have a DB with fields like below

Latitude     Longitude   Flag
54.1425      98.2564     0
52.1036      94.1458     3
51.1569      92.1458     3
50.1326      91.1458     3
56.1236      93.1458     0

I need to retrieve records that have flag as 3.

```
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest()

    let appDelegate =
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext

    let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("TABLE_LOCATION", inManagedObjectContext: managedContext)




    // Configure Fetch Request
    fetchRequest.entity = entityDescription


    do {
        let result = try managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)
        //print(result)


    } catch {
        let fetchError = error as NSError
        print(fetchError)
    }
```

All i have is the above code that retrieves all records from the table TABLE_LOCATION any code or working example is much appreciated

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add a NSPredicate to your fetchRequest.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPredicate_Class/

```
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "flag == %@", "3")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a NSPredicate and set it to the fetchRequest. Create a NSPredicate and set it to the fetchRequest before you execute the fetch request.

```
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "flag = 3")
```

Answer (score 0):

Change Your function to:

```
func fetchDistinctDataUsingReq(predicate :NSPredicate) -> NSArray {
   let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest()
   fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
   //Rest of your code
}
```

Now call this function from using:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "flag == %@", 3)
self.fetchDistinctDataUsingReq(predicate)
```

This is a much better approach and can be reused across fetching. Additionally you can pass the CoreData Table as parameter along with predicate to generalize it.